# How can I access UITextFields from outside the ViewController (from a .m file)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class where I keep utility methods; one of those methods takes the values in some textboxes stored in a ViewController and saves those values to a plist.

The problem is the utility methods class is not a ViewController and therefore I can't "hook up" the outlet properties of the textboxes tothe Utility class.

Is there a way I can pass the ViewController as a parameter to the Utility class method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the utilities class a Singleton inheriting just from NSObject. That way you can easily access the methods wherever you'd like and you'll only have one instance of it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Singleton.html

Matt Gallagher wrote a great helper file to create Singletons. Check it out here:

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Comment: Make "what" a singleton class?  I have 24 UITextFields that need to be stored in the plist.

Comment: Isn't the utlities class filled with generic methods? Just call the methods inside of your VC (after you make the utilities class a singleton)

Comment: Yes, one to load a UITableView, the other will be to save the contents of the textboxes when I leave the page where they are possibly modified...

Can you explain to me "why" I want to make the Utility class a singleton?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my situation clearly... I have a ViewController that displays the textboxes; I have a CommonMethods.m file where I can access methods from anywhere in the app; one of those routines saves the contents of the textboxes to the plist.  The problem is I can't access the textboxes from the CommonMethods.m file.

Comment: That doesn't seem like the cleanest way to handle what you're doing. If your wanting to access the values stored inside of these textFields its easier just to keep the values inside of NSUserDefaults. That way theyll persist between launches and you can access the values anywhere. If youre going to use the commonMethods class, I'd definitely recommend making make the methods generic at least

Comment: @tdevoy: what's the benefit of using NSUserDefaults vs Plists?  The values in the textboxes can be altered by the user...

Comment: @hashier:  was trying to save the data to a versioned CoreData store, but the migration wasn't working, and I have already spent too much time working on the problem; this is the best alternative, even better than the CoreData store.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is not an option -- it's immutable... :-{

Comment: How is NSUserDefaults immutable?

Comment: `Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string as the value for "MyStringDefault", the string you later retrieve using stringForKey: will be immutable.`

I think I've figured it out... taking the values of the textboxes and putting in a NSMutableArray, which will be passed to the common method.

Comment: Dude you just overwrite the values inside of NSUserDefaults when the text changes. Piece of cake. But if you've got a another method, cheers!

Comment: @tdevoy: Thanks for all of your help... it got me going in the right direction, and passing an array with the textbox values works great!  Thanks again! :D

SD

Comment: @spokane-dude no probb. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

If these utility methodes are class methods use a singleton. Something like this:

```
+ (__CMMotionManager__ *)__sharedMotionManager__ {
    static __CMMotionManager__ *shared = nil;
    if (!shared) {
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{ // all threads will block here until the block executes
            shared = [[__CMMotionManager__ alloc] init]; // this line of code can only ever happen once
        });
    }
    return shared;
}
```

(it's my CoreMotionManager snippet)